# How to create own plugin for Grafana

Tags: plugins, panel, grafana

I just started with grafana and would like to try to develop my own plugin to use it beside Graph, Singlestat, Dashlist, and Text panels. I found only these links about that :
http://docs.grafana.org/plugins/panels/,
https://grafana.net/resources/getting-started-with-plugins
Is anybody have ideas which environment could be used for developing grafana plugin and from where possible to start?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a detailed walkthrough of the creation of the Clock panel plugin available on the grafana blog: [Part 1](https://grafana.com/blog/2016/04/08/timing-is-everything.-writing-the-clock-panel-plugin-for-grafana-3.0/) & [Part 2](https://grafana.com/blog/2016/04/15/timing-is-everything.-editor-mode-in-grafana-3.0-for-the-clock-panel-plugin/)

That's definitely a good place to start.  As far an an environment, you'll obviously need a grafana instance, and you'll also need node & npm to be able to run the grunt-based build process.

Part 1 of the walkthrough should have enough detail to get you started, there is also a pretty active community on the grafana irc and slack channels who can help with specific questions.

Comment: The worked example of a custom panel doesn't use a datasource.  Sad!